# Image swap jquery mouseover

Tags: jquery, image, mouseover, swap, mouseout

I am currently having some problems getting a mouseover and mouseout function to work in jquery. I have two images called 'images/doomsday.jpg' and the other called 'keep_calm.png' which i want to swap when the mouse is over them and then swap back when it is not. I have included the code I am currently trying to use, can anybody see any problems with it and where I am going wrong?

```
$(function() {
$("images/doomsday.jpg")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "images/keep_calm.png";
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("images/keep_calm.png");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 7):

Your selectors are wrong. You can learn about the selectors [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/asalod/2/edit) of image swapping.

Code :

```
$('document').ready(function() {

  $('img').on({
    'mouseover' : function() {
      $(this).attr('src','http://media02.hongkiat.com/css3-code-slim/css3-markup.jpg');
    },
    mouseout : function() {
  $(this).attr('src','http://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_512.png');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this **DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/m4WuU/ just use Jquery [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

HTML

```
 <div class="holder"><div>
```

CSS:

```
 .holder { 
     background-image:url('images/keep_calm.png');         
  }


.swapHolder { 
   background-image:url('images/doomsday.png'); 
 }
```

JS:

```
$('.holder').on('hover', function () {  
   $('.holder').toggleClass('swapHolder'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There were no selectors used. Here's how your final code should look like

The HTML

```
<div> <img src="images/doomsday.jpg" id='myimage' /> </div>
```

The Javascript

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$(function() {
$("#myimage")
    .mouseover(function() { 
        var src = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "images/keep_calm.png";
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("images/keep_calm.png");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the selector is wrong:
You should use for example `$("#imageid")` where image id is the id of the image you want to change.